Why is my angular reactive form producing the following error: updateTreeValidity is not a function
When the form is initially accessed I get the following error:

ERROR TypeError: this.form._updateTreeValidity is not a function
_updateDomValue
ngOnChanges

For each character I enter into a field, I get this error:

ERROR TypeError: this.form.get is not a function
_setUpFormContainer
addFormGroup
ngOnInit

My form:
<form [formGroup]="checkoutForm" (ngSubmit)="placeOrder()">
    <section>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col col-12 col-lg-8">
                <div formGroupName="deliveryAddress">
                    <div class="row mb-4">
                        <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">First Name</label>
                            <input id="firstName" class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" 
                                required formControlName="firstName"
                                (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                        </div>
                
                        <div class="col">
                            <label class="form-label">Last Name</label>
                            <input id="lastName" class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" 
                                required formControlName="lastName"
                                (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                        </div>
                
                
                        <div class="row mb-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label class="form-label">Phone Number</label>
                                <input id="phone" class="form-control fw-bold" type="phone" 
                                    required formControlName="phone"
                                    (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label class="form-label">Delivery Address</label>
                                <input id="address1" class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" 
                                    required formControlName="address1"
                                    (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <label class="form-label">Delivery Address Line 2 (Optional)</label>
                                <input id="address2" class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" formControlName="address2"                                 
                                    (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input id="useAsBillingAddress" class="form-check-input" type="checkbox"
                                        formControlName="useAsBillingAddress" (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="formCheck-1">Use as Billing
                                        Address</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                
                
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div formGroupName="applianceDelivery">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col d-flex flex-column col-12 col-md-4">
                            <img src="assets/img/deliverytruck.png"
                                style="width: 64px;">
                            <div>
                                <small class="me-2">{{cart?.length}}</small>
                                <small>Item(s)</small>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col" style="font-size: 14px;">
                            <h6>Select Delivery Date</h6>
                            <input id="deliveryDate" class="form-control fw-bold mb-2" type="date" 
                                required formControlName="deliveryDate"
                                (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                
                            <small class="fw-normal" style="font-size: 14.3px;">We'll call or text (617)
                                567-7112 with your projected 4-hour delivery window one business day
                                before your scheduled delivery date. You may also receive an optional
                                customer service satisfaction survey.</small>
                            <p class="mt-4">Delivery Instructions:</p>
                            <textarea id="specialInstructions" class="form-control" 
                                formControlName="specialInstructions"
                                (change)="saveToDataStore()"></textarea>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            
                <div formGroupName="paymentMethod">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="row mb-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="paymentType1" value="PayPal"
                                        formControlName="paymentType" (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="paymentType1" style="font-style: italic;">PayPal</label>
                                </div>
                                <div cl ass="form-check">
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" id="paymentType2"
                                        value="Credit Card" formControlName="paymentType" (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="paymentType2">Credit Card</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-4">
                            <div class="col">
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-text ps-0">
                                        <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input id="cardNumber" class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" 
                                        required formControlName="cardNumber"
                                        (change)="saveToDataStore()" placeholder="Enter credit card number">
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary d-none" type="button">Button</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="row mb-4">
                            <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <small>Expiration Month</small>
                                <select id="expMonth" class="form-select fw-bold" formControlName="expMonth" (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                                    <optgroup label="Month">
                                        <option *ngFor="let expMonth of expirationMonths"> {{expMonth}}
                                        </option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <small>Expiration Year</small>
                                <select id="expYear" class="form-select fw-bold" formControlName="expYear" (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                                    <optgroup label="Year">
                                        <option *ngFor="let expYear of expirationYears">
                                            {{expYear}}
                                        </option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <small>CVV (on back)</small>
                                <div class="input-group">
                                    <span class="input-group-text ps-0">
                                        <i class="fa fa-credit-card-alt" style="font-size: 25px;"></i>
                                    </span>
                                    <input id="CVV" class="form-control fw-bold" type="text" maxlength="3" formControlName="CVV"
                                        (change)="saveToDataStore()" placeholder="Enter CVV">
                
                                    <button class="btn btn-primary d-none" type="button">Button</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-12 mt-4">
                                <div class="form-check">                                 
                                    <input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" id="saveAsDefaultCard" 
                                        formControlName="saveAsDefaultCard"
                                        (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                                    <label class="form-check-label" for="saveAsDefaultCard" style="font-size: 13px;">Save as my default credit
                                        card</label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="col col-12 col-md-4">
                <app-order-summary></app-order-summary>

                <section class="mt-5">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary w-100 primary-button" type="submit"
                        (click)="placeOrder()"
                        style="font-size: 20px;font-weight: bold;">Place Order</button>
                </section>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</form>

The component:
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FormControl, FormGroup, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { Store } from '@ngrx/store';
import { ToastrService } from 'ngx-toastr';
import { OrderSummaryComponent } from '../order/order-summary/order-summary.component';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { storeCheckoutData } from '../checkout/checkout.actions';
import { CheckoutService } from '../checkout/checkout.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-checkout2',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    CommonModule,
    OrderSummaryComponent
  ],
  templateUrl: './checkout2.component.html',
  styleUrl: './checkout2.component.scss'
})
export class Checkout2Component {
  checkoutForm: FormGroup = new FormGroup({});
  public cart;
  public checkoutData;
  public expirationMonths;
  public expirationYears;

  constructor(
    private store:Store<{cartReducers, checkoutReducers}>,
    private checkoutService:CheckoutService,
    private toastr: ToastrService,
  ){}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.initCheckoutForm();
    this.subscribeToRedux();        

  }

  private subscribeToRedux = () => {

    const cartReducers$ = this.store.select((state) => {
      return state.cartReducers;
    });

    cartReducers$.subscribe((cartReducers:any) => {
      this.cart = cartReducers.cart;
     console.log('CheckoutComponent.cart', this.cart)
    });

    const checkoutReducers$ = this.store.select((state) => {
      return state.checkoutReducers;
    });

    checkoutReducers$.subscribe((checkoutReducers:any) => {

      if(Object.keys(checkoutReducers?.checkoutData).length > 0) {
        this.checkoutData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(checkoutReducers.checkoutData));

  
        this.checkoutForm = {...this.checkoutData}

        // console.log('this.checkoutData 2', this.checkoutData);
      console.log('ChecoutComponent.checkoutForm 2', this.checkoutForm);
      }
  
  
      this.expirationMonths = checkoutReducers.expirationMonths;
      this.expirationYears = checkoutReducers.expirationYears;
      console.log('CheckoutComponent.checkoutData', this.checkoutData)
      console.log('CheckoutComponent.expirationMonths', this.expirationMonths)
      console.log('CheckoutComponent.expirationYears', this.expirationYears)
    });
  }

  private initCheckoutForm = () => {
    this.checkoutForm = new FormGroup({
      deliveryAddress: new FormGroup({ 
        firstName: new FormControl(''),
        lastName: new FormControl(''),
        phone: new FormControl(''),
        address1: new FormControl(''),
        address2: new FormControl(''),
        useAsBillingAddress: new FormControl(''),
      }),
      applianceDelivery: new FormGroup({ 
          deliveryDate: new FormControl(''),
          specialInstructions: new FormControl(''),
      }),
      paymentMethod: new FormGroup({ 
          paymentType: new FormControl(''),
          cardNumber: new FormControl(''),
          expMonth: new FormControl(''),
          expYear: new FormControl(''),
          CVV: new FormControl(''),
          defaultCreditCard: new FormControl(''),
    })
    });

    console.log('this.checkoutForm', this.checkoutForm.value);
  }

  public saveToDataStore = () => {
     this.store.dispatch(storeCheckoutData({checkoutData: this.checkoutData}))
  }

  public placeOrder = () => {    
    const hdepot = localStorage.getItem('hdepot');
    let token = null;

    if(hdepot) {
      token = JSON.parse(hdepot).user.token;
    }

    console.log('token', token)

    if(!token) {
      this.toastr.warning('Please sign in to place an order.', '');
      return;
    }    

    const items = [];

    for(let item of this.cart) {
      items.push (
         {
          product: item.product._id,
          quantity: item.quantity,
          color: item.color,
          size: item.size
        }
      )
    }

    this.checkoutData = {...this.checkoutForm}
    this.checkoutData.items = items;
    console.log('CheckoutComponent.checkoutData 2', this.checkoutData)
    this.checkoutService.placeOrder(this.checkoutData)
  }
}


You must have strict mode turned off, given all the untyped variables.  You're issue is that you reassign checkoutForm to a value that is another type other than FormGroup.  That is why the errors are complaining about missing functions.
This issue I spotted occurs in the following snippet:
checkoutReducers$.subscribe((checkoutReducers:any) => {
  if(Object.keys(checkoutReducers?.checkoutData).length > 0) {
    this.checkoutData = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(checkoutReducers.checkoutData));
    //  checkoutData IS NOT a ForGroup!  
    this.checkoutForm = {...this.checkoutData}
    // console.log('this.checkoutData 2', this.checkoutData);
    console.log('ChecoutComponent.checkoutForm 2', this.checkoutForm);
  }
  /* ... */
}


You probably meant to do something like this.checkoutForm.setValue(this.checkoutData);
Your code is probably not in a state where you can quickly turn on more robust type checking.  At the very least consider the following:

Make checkoutForm readonly so that it isn't accidently reassigned again.
Set the value of checkoutForm when it is initialized.  There's nothing gained by waiting for the OnInit lifecycle event and you never intentionally reassign the value anywhere else.

