How do I bind an Angular reactive form selectbox field to the attribute in the underlying component?
The values of my selectboxes in my reactive form are not binding to the component's formcontrol.
Here I have a date element that I expect to populate the deliveryDate field but the it is not populated:
<div formGroupName="applianceDelivery">
    <div class="col" style="font-size: 14px;">
       <h6>Select Delivery Date</h6>
       <input id="deliveryDate" class="form-control fw-bold mb-2" type="date" 
          required formControlName="deliveryDate"
          (change)="saveToDataStore()">
    </div>
</div>

Here is the form group in the component:
private initCheckoutForm = () => {
this.checkoutForm = new FormGroup({
  deliveryAddress: new FormGroup({ 
    firstName: new FormControl(''),
    lastName: new FormControl(''),
    phone: new FormControl(''),
    address1: new FormControl(''),
    address2: new FormControl(''),
    useAsBillingAddress: new FormControl(''),
  }),
  applianceDelivery: new FormGroup({ 
      deliveryDate: new FormControl(),
      specialInstructions: new FormControl(''),
  }),
  paymentMethod: new FormGroup({ 
      paymentType: new FormControl(''),
      cardNumber: new FormControl(''),
      expMonth: new FormControl(''),
      expYear: new FormControl(''),
      CVV: new FormControl(''),
      defaultCreditCard: new FormControl(''),
  })
});

console.log('this.checkoutForm', this.checkoutForm.value);

}
These do not work either:
<div class="row mb-4">
                            <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <small>Expiration Month</small>
                                <select id="expMonth" class="form-select fw-bold" 
                                    formControlName="expMonth" 
                                    (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                                    <optgroup label="Month">
                                        <option *ngFor="let expMonth of expirationMonths"> {{expMonth}}
                                        </option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
                                <small>Expiration Year</small>
                                <select id="expYear" 
                                    class="form-select fw-bold" formControlName="expYear" 
                                    (change)="saveToDataStore()">
                                    <optgroup label="Year">
                                        <option *ngFor="let expYear of expirationYears">
                                            {{expYear}}
                                        </option>
                                    </optgroup>
                                </select>
                            </div>


please share a simple stackblitz with the issue happening, this code does not highlight the complete form structure in HTML

@Naren The entire form can be found in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78889175/why-is-my-angular-reactive-form-producing-the-following-error-updatetreevalidit/78889414#78889414

I don't see any patch value in your code, which actually sets the data on the form. Also please share the data object you are trying to patch on the form

When you patch the value after you fetch the data, it must follow the same structure as the form group.
this.checkoutForm.patchValue({
  deliveryAddress: { 
    firstName: 'firstName',
    lastName: 'lastName',
    phone: 'phone',
    address1: 'address1',
    address2: 'address2',
    useAsBillingAddress: 'useAsBillingAddress',
  },
  applianceDelivery: { 
      deliveryDate: 'deliveryDate',
      specialInstructions: 'specialInstructions',
  },
  paymentMethod: { 
      paymentType: 'paymentType',
      cardNumber: 'cardNumber',
      expMonth: 'expMonth',
      expYear: 'expYear',
      CVV: 'CVV',
      defaultCreditCard: 'defaultCreditCard',
  }
});

You have to specify the [value] option for the select in-order for the select to work.
<div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
     <small>Expiration Month</small>
     <select id="expMonth" class="form-select fw-bold" 
          formControlName="expMonth" 
          (change)="saveToDataStore()">
          <optgroup label="Month">
               <option *ngFor="let expMonth of expirationMonths" [value]="expMonth"> <!-- changed here! -->
                   {{expMonth}}
               </option>
          </optgroup>
     </select>
</div>
<div class="col col-12 col-lg-4">
    <small>Expiration Year</small>
    <select id="expYear" class="form-select fw-bold" formControlName="expYear" (change)="saveToDataStore()">
         <optgroup label="Year">
             <option *ngFor="let expYear of expirationYears" [value]="expYear">
                  {{expYear}}
             </option>
         </optgroup>
    </select>
 </div>

